# Не получается конвертировать oga в wav

Tags: python, ffmpeg

```
import glob
import ffmpeg 

out_put = (

ffmpeg.input('file_60.oga')
.output('file_60.wav', format='wav')
.overwrite_output()
.run())
```

Выдает такую ошибку `module 'ffmpeg' has no attribute 'input'`

Как исправить?

**UPD.**

```
import glob
from ffmpeg import FFmpeg

out_put=(FFmpeg().option('y')
                .input('file_60.oga')
               .output('file_60.wav'))
```

Теперь ошибок не выдает, но и результата 0

Comment: в вы документацию читали? https://pypi.org/project/python-ffmpeg/

Comment: Меняя текст вопроса, оставляйте контекст, а то ответ теряет смысл :)

Comment: @strawdog, у автора, похоже, эта библиотека используется: https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python . Судя по коду в UPD, класс `Ffmpeg` относится к другой библиотеке - https://github.com/jonghwanhyeon/python-ffmpeg :D

Comment: Подозреваю, что нужно еще сам `FFmpeg` установить и мб чтобы оно было доступно из консоли, добавив путь к нему в переменную окружения `PATH`

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg` - это **модуль**.

В нем находится **класс** `Ffmpeg` (с прописной буквой в начале).

Нужно создать **объект** этого класса (например добавлением скобок после его имени) и только к нему применить методы `.input()`, `.output()` и т.д.

Значит вместо ваших строк

```
ffmpeg.input('file_60.oga')
.output('file_60.wav', format='wav')
```

Примените

```
ffmpeg.Ffmpeg().input('file_60.oga')
               .output('file_60.wav')   # f='wav' не надо; ваше format='wav' неправильно
```

Это только что касается вашей ошибки

> ```
> module 'ffmpeg' has no attribute 'input'
> ```

Затем нужно исправить другие вещи (как несуществование метода `.overwrite_output()` - надо применить `.option("y")`) и вообще неправильную структуру вашей программы.

Comment: Я поправил код, но результат он не выдает.

Comment: А ваш ответ по какой библиотеке сделан? https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python или https://github.com/jonghwanhyeon/python-ffmpeg? :D

Comment: А какую надо, и зачем они наплодили клоны?

Comment: Я установил 1, код выдавал ошибку, я задал сюда вопрос, потом переделал  код и усьанвил вторую, первую снес